# Python / Selenium clicking on elements in a table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a web table, and in the second column of the table is an item that can be selected.  This is the code I am working with:

```
animal_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="threeanlDocViewTb3"]/tbody')
animal_count = 0

rows = animal_name.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
for row in rows:
    col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')[2]
    print(col.text)
    animal_count = animal_count + 1
    
print('Total animals: ', animal_count)
```

This code returns the following output:

```
Cat
Dog
Bird
Total animals: 3
```

Each of these animals can be clicked on, which will return a nested folder that might contain another folder, or a text file.  If the folder contains a nested folder I would like to click on it and keep going.  If it has a text file I would like to read it.

So to do this, I am trying to click on the element.  The only thing I can think of doing is something like this:

```
for row in rows:
    driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')[2].click
```

This returns the error "TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable".  After reading about this error, it sounds like what I am trying to do shouldn't require the '[2]' and to remove it, but this is the only way I can choose the correct column.

How would I go about clicking on the animals?

Comment: `row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')[2].click()`?

Comment: That returns 'TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: `find_elements()`?

Comment: Post the URL to have a look.

Comment: Thank you.  find_elements() worked.